# How can we change the facebook apprequests Notification message

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to change the notification message in facebook from "invited you to play" from something else while invite users for the app. Below is my code which i am trying

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'invite you for my network',
        action_type:'askfor',
        object_id: '750142945086128', 
        title:'People waiting to play with you, play now!',
        new_style_message: true,
        template:'You have people waiting to play with you, play now'
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

That´s not possible, and you are using a lot of non-existing parameters. See the docs for all available ones: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests

All you can change is the `message`:

> A plain-text message to be sent as part of the request. This text will surface in the App Center view of the request, but not on the notification jewel

Requests are for games only, how to invite users to games and non-games is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Comment: I have added the parms after research on the google. Do you have any idea  why FB didn't provided this option. Is there any security concern?

Comment: always use the official docs, they tell you exactly which parameters exist. not sure why facebook didn´t provide it, but those requests are for games, so there should be no need to change it.

Comment: If my use case is different from gaming then what alternatives are available to me within FB?

Comment: i will something about that in my answer. but app requests are for games only, you can´t use them for anything else.